# Select array element by criteria in MongoDB aggregation $addFields

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

My collection's structure is this:

```
[
    { key: 'a', type: 'one', content: { ... } },
    { key: 'a', type: 'two', content: { ... } },
    { key: 'b', type: 'one', content: { ... } }
]
```

I need a query that returns this:

```
[
    { key: 'a', one: { ... }, two: { ... } },
    { key: 'b', one: { ... }, two: null }
]
```

(The `two: null` thing would be a bonus, I'm also happy with `two` simply being undefined.)

I started the aggregation with grouping by `key`:

```
{ $group: { 
    _id: '$key',
    key: { $first: '$key' },
    contents: { $push: '$content' } 
} }
```

And thought I could then do something like:

```
{ $addFields: {
    one: '$contents[type=one]',
    two: '$contents[type=two]'
} }
```

But obviously it doesn't work like that. I experimented a bit with `$filter` but couldn't get it to work.

How can I realise "`$contents[type=one]`"? Or, alternatively, how can I achieve my desired output with a different approach?

Answer (score 0):

Just before hitting "Post your question" I came across `$arrayElemAt` once more. I previously ignored it because I thought I didn't know the index and instead needed something like `$arrayElemWhere`, which doesn't exist. But then I realised: It's perfectly possible to know the index! Here's how:

While pushing the `content`s, simultaneously push the `type`s, too:

```
{ $group: { 
    _id: '$key',
    key: { $first: '$key' },
    contents: { $push: '$content' },
    types: { $push: '$type' }
} }
```

Then dynamically query the `types` array for the index and use it on the `contents` array:

```
{ $addFields: {
    one: { $arrayElemAt: [
        '$contents',
        { $indexOfArray: ['$types', 'one'] }
    ] }
} }
```

Hope this helps someone. Other answers/links to duplicates welcome (I couldn't find my case anywhere...)